# JQERY передача свойств из массива в .on()

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы, методы

Здравствуйте!

Имеются вот такие не сложные функции

```
$('.js-dashboard__button_clear').on('click',() => {
    observer.clearField();
});

$('.js-dashboard__button_start').on('click',() => {
    observer.startGame()
});

$('.js-dashboard__input_row').on('focusout',() => {
    observer.changeSizeField();
});

$('.js-dashboard__input_column').on('focusout',() => {
    observer.changeSizeField();
});

$('.js-dashboard__button_pause').on('click',() => {
    observer.pauseGame();
});

$('.js-dashboard__button_random').on('click',() => {
    observer.createRandomField();
});

$('.js-field__container').on('click', '.js-field__cell',(event: any)=>{
    observer.changeTypeCell(event);
});
```

Необходимо реализовать передачу свойств из массива(класс, тип события, вложенный объект observer) в общую функцию `$().on()` и затем перебором их все создавать.

Возможно ли это реализовать?

Comment: где массив свойства которого надо передавать? что нужно создавать перебором?

Comment: Пусть будет const array = [[.js-dashboard__button_clear, 'click', observer.clearField(); ],[],[]]

Comment: понятно, и зачем это нужно?

Comment: Чтобы в конструкторе класса создать массив, а потом одним приватным методом генерировать все события,  работать с одним массивом а не добавлять функции.

Comment: так создайте просто функцию инициализирующую эти обработчики и дергайте в своем конструкторе функцию...

Comment: Я и прошу подсказать как должна выглядеть эта функция) Не получается написать чтобы заработало(

Comment: Возможно я ошибаюсь, но на мой взгляд вы хотите ухудшить читаемость в угоду мнимой оптимизации. Засуньте  эти слушатели по разным методам и один метод который вызывает все остальные ...